# Is f(x)=-log(x) a closed function?

Tags: convex-optimization

I am reading ***Convex optimization*** written by Stephen Boyd. In page 640, there is an example said 
\begin{equation}
f(x)=-log(x)
\end{equation}
is a closed function. But this function seems does not satisfy the definition of closed function in this book.
The plot of this function is attached below:
[image]
And the definition of closed function in the book is attached below:
[image]

Can anybody tell me whether this function is closed or not ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $dom\ f = (0,\infty),$ and for any $\alpha \in\mathbb R$
$$
x\in\ dom\ f\ and\ f(x) \leq \alpha \Leftrightarrow x \ge e^{-\alpha} \Leftrightarrow x \in [e^{-\alpha},\infty).
$$
Now, the set $[e^{-\alpha},\infty)$ is closed, so $f$ is a closed function, according to the definition.

Comment: Is $[e^{-\alpha},\infty)$ closed ?? I think it's a left-closed and right-open interval.

Comment: It's closed because its complement ($-\infty$,$e^{-\alpha}$) is open.

Comment: I re-read the definition of closed set in page 638 of Convex Optimization. Although kind of confused, but I will take it as a standard explanation. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

It's closed. It's level sets are of the form $[b, \infty[$ and hence, closed.

Comment: What is $[b,\infty[$ ?

Comment: The same as $[b,\infty)$…

Comment: But $[b,\infty)$ is not closed, right?

Comment: A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is closed if every convergent sequence in said set has it's limit in the set. Do you see now, why it is closed?